# Player controlled node ignoring collisions

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have a SKShapeNode controlled by the player. I want to keep this node inside a parent node. So I created edges and I use SKPhysicsBody and collision bit mask to prevent my node from moving outside its parent.

When I try to move the node by updating its position each frame, it just ignores the edges. Here is the function used :

```
func move(direction: MoveDirection, withTimeInterval timeInterval: TimeInterval) {

    var x, y: CGFloat

    switch direction {
    case .North:
        x = 0
        y = movementSpeed * CGFloat(timeInterval)

    case .South:
        x = 0
        y = -movementSpeed * CGFloat(timeInterval)

    case .East:
        x = movementSpeed * CGFloat(timeInterval)
        y = 0

    case .West:
        x = -movementSpeed * CGFloat(timeInterval)
        y = 0
    }

    let sprite = spriteComponent.sprite
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x + x, y: sprite.position.y + y)

}
```

The moving works great but the node can go everywhere and just doesn't care about the edges (I turned skView.showPhysics on so I can see them).

But, if I replace the line :

```
sprite.position = CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x + x, y: sprite.position.y + y)
```

by :

```
sprite.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: x, dy: y))
```

collisions work just fine.

It feels like we have to move objects using physics if we want them to collide. But I didn't see anything about this restriction in Apple's doc. So is this behavior expected? Or did I miss something?

Bonus point :

In the TaskBot game provided by Apple, the player's position is (or seems) changed by setting node.position (the code is a bit...complicated, so not really sure). If someone can give me a hint?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move an SKSpriteNode manually, there will be no collisions because you are overriding the physics engine by saying "Put this node there no matter what".

If you want the physics engine to reliably generate collisions, then you'll need to use only the physics engine to move your objects via forces or impulses.

If you manually move a node into a position where it generates a collision, the the physics engine will attempt to move it away, but if you carry on trying to move the node, results will be unpredictable.

Comment: SKAction has the same issue. Based on some tests, if the action time is too short it will not collide (I used update() timeInterval as action duration). The issue in my case is the move function being called in update(). If I call it directly in keyDown(), collision works fine. But event there, if I set a high moving speed, collisions start failing again. In a nutshell, use physics (force, impulse, etc.) to move physics bodies

Comment: Actually every manual position change will interfere with a physics system in some way. Sticking to one or thr other is always the best option, but also that is not a rule. Still if you should avoid affecting on the node's position in multiple ways at the same time.

Comment: Just FYI, I tried lowering the movementSpeed in my code and the collision works. I also tried to increase the speed in Apple's Taskbot game and the same issue shows up. Anyway, thanks for the hint

Comment: Why don't you use contacts instead of collisions? When the player contacts the edge, stop it moving. Or use an SKConstraint to limit its position or limit it in didFinishUpdate.

Comment: @Heyfara This is what Whirlwind was alluding to - manual movement can work,  but it's not reliable as you have proven to yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but using physics to move my node is fine. My question here was more about understanding what was happening rather than finding a solution.